# Match regex that doesn't start with something

Tags: regex

I have seen a few other similar questions, but I can't seem to get it to work.  What I am trying to do is in JavaScript match a string with issue numbers.  I have that part working fine, but I don't want to match it if it starts with `target='_blank'>`.

These should match...

```
Issue# 123  
Issue #123  
Issue 123  
Issue no 123  
Issue number 123  
Issue: 123
```

These should not...

```
target='_blank'>Issue# 123  
target='_blank'>Issue #123  
target='_blank'>Issue 123  
target='_blank'>Issue no 123  
target='_blank'>Issue number 123  
target='_blank'>Issue: 123
```

What I have so far is

```
(?!target='_blank'>)(issue(?: number| no)?[ #:]?[ #]?([0-9]+))
```

But it is still matching the ones it shouldn't.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Apparently JS doesn't support lookbehinds, otherwise this would be easy.

Comment: Why not just examine the value returned by `.slice(0, 16)`? If it's equal to `"target='_blank'>"` then the overall string doesn't match.

Comment: So your parsing HTML with regex?

Comment: I'm not really trying to parse HTML with regex, I am looking for any instances of the issue, and wrapping them with a link.  The reason for not wanting the target is a simple way to tell if I am wrapping a link with a link.

Comment: @Justin: The usual speech about not parsing HTML with regex is wrong and is usually delivered by someone who is merely quoting a funny post without actually understanding it. You can not consume arbitrary HTML expressions for processing (i.e. - you can't understand the syntax of HTML as regex is not equipped to do so). You can however process a known set of HTML as if it was text with out any problems (scraping a page once for information, for example). It may be hard to maintain as it *is* regex, and there may be a better solution, but it will still work. /rant

Comment: Paul, please check your assumptions about my intentions and what I do and do not understand. If you want to rant, start a blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys,

What I've ended up having to do is as suggested [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), and reverse the string and my regex, and use look ahead.

So my new regex is

```
(([0-9]+)[ #]?[ #:]?(?:rebmun |on )?eussi)(?!>'knalb_'=tegrat)
```

lame.

Answer (score 2):

You're using negative look ahead when you should be using negative look behind.

```
(?<!target='_blank'>)(issue(?: number| no)?[ #:]?[ #]?([0-9]+))
```

Note the `?<!` instead of `?!`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^(Issue(?: number| no)?[ #:]?[ #]?([0-9]+))` (Untested)

If you're trying to parse HTML with Regex. Please don't, instead.. Use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 0):

Glossing over the usual speech about "don't parse HTML with regexes",... if you're using jQuery, you could do something like

```
$("a[target!='_blank']").each(function() {
    if(/yourregex/.match($(this).text()) {
        // do whatever
    }
});
```

That probably "won't compile", but that's the general idea.